# Как перехватить запрос к несуществующему контролеру в Asp Net Core?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp-net-core-mvc

Что я имею в виду.
У меня стандартный роутинг

```html
app.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

Также у меня 1 контроллер  `HomeController` 
Одно приложение обрабатывает сразу много сайтов.

```html
example.com
sub.example.com
sub1.example.com
......
example1.com
sub.example1.com
sub1.example1.com
......
example1.com
......
```

Но при обращении к `example1.com/level2/` `sub.example1.com/level2/` ошибка `404`
Такие запросы должен обрабатывать контроллер `level2Controller` но его нет и не будет. 
Вот мне нужно перехватить запрос после того как контроллер не был найдет и обработать его. В данном случае сделать редиректор на главную страницу сайта.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-7.0